# android baseadapter return custom class not string

Tags: android, android-spinner, baseadapter, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

i'm working baseadapter.i have  custom baseadapter.i use my adapter in spinner.i have one problem.mybaseadapter's OnItemClickedListener returned all my custom class

carbon.widget.Spinner$CustomClass@535ca050s

this is a result
this is a my code

```
  public static class CustomClass {
    private String Name;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.Name=name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    public CustomClass(String name)
    {
        this.Name=name;
    }
}

public static class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder, CustomClass> {

   private ArrayList<CustomClass>items=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public CustomClass getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carbon_popup_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        holder.tv.setText(items.get(position).getName());
        Log.e("position String", items.get(position).getName() + "s");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    public void setItems(ArrayList<CustomClass> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.carbon_itemText);

    }
}
```

i inserted some values in my baseadapter like this

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        CustomClass customClass = new CustomClass("item" + i);
        // customClass.setName("beka" + i);
        list.add(customClass);
    }

    Spinner day = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.day);
    day.setItems(list);
```

this is a my setItem method

```
 public void setItems(ArrayList<CustomClass> items) {
    popupMenu.setAdapter(defaultAdapter);
    defaultAdapter.setOnItemClickedListener(onItemClickedListener);
    defaultAdapter.setItems(items);
}




  RecyclerView.OnItemClickedListener onItemClickedListener = new RecyclerView.OnItemClickedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(int position) {
        setText(popupMenu.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString());
        Log.e("position String",popupMenu.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString()+"s");
        popupMenu.dismiss();
    }
};
```

as i said i can't return my custom class's getName. how i can solve my problem? if anyone knows solution please help me
p.s
i try to rewrite this example

> https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon

in this example autor used String arrays but i want to use my Custom Array
how i can solve my problem?

Comment: Ask your question properly

Comment: @Jas when i log in my log i can't show myCustomClass'getName value (pleasee see where i use Log.e).carbon.widget.Spinner$CustomClass@535ca050s this is a output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`popupMenu.getAdapter().getItem(position)` is returning `CustomClass` in your, and since you didn't override `toString()` in it, you are seeing the default implementation of `Object.toString()`. For the sake oh showing the name you could override it and return name. E.g.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return name != null ? name : "no name set";
}
```

Alternatively you can simply call  `popupMenu.getAdapter().getItem(position).getName()`

E.g.

```
CustomClass objectAtPos = popupMenu.getAdapter().getItem(position);
 if (objectAtPos != null) {
    setText(objectAtPos.getName());
    Log.e("position String",objectAtPos.getName()+"s");
 }
 popupMenu.dismiss();
```

Comment: thanks but in first time i can't show my first value in Spinner.how i can solve it?

Comment: what do you mean by *the first time*

Comment: first time  i can't see anythink in spiiner but when i click it i can show my all values(items) @Blackbelt

Comment: do you have any idea?